# A program where parent process creates a child process and both parent and child run same program different code

Tags: c, unix, process, fork

```
//same program different code
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0)
    {
        printf("\n Error ");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("\n Hello I am the child process ");
        printf("\n My pid is %d ",getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Hello I am the parent process ");
        printf("\n My actual pid is %d \n ",getpid());
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

I tried this , I hope its correct .
But I am not satisfied with the output .

The output is :

```
 Hello I am the parent process 
 My actual pid is 4287 
 ashu@ashu-VirtualWorld:~/Desktop/4thSemester/testprep$ 
 Hello I am the child process 
 My pid is 4288
```

Please help me I cant understand its output , I want the child process to occur first and then parent process .
Also , when the execution ends the control is transferred to the program , so to return to terminal I have to use ctrl+c , I want that after the execution of the program ends the control transfers to the terminal .

Comment: Why do you want parallel programming, if you want something to 'occur first'? Why not just write in sequence then? That said, there's a myriad of options for you to go, for example the use of Mutexes, delays, etc...but for your scenario, you don't need parallel processes at all.

Comment: I did write the child process in order first , but am getting Parent process first :( 
Also am new to terms like mutexes,delays !

Comment: Yeah, the answer of unwind says it pretty much precisely...they're supposed to run in parallel. Which means they both get their own time slices of processor time and take turns in 'executing' (basics of multitasking). Now, your child process will pretty much always be a little behind your parent process, because the parent process is still 'it' until the end of its current time slice, while the child process has to wait his turn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing with parallel processes is that they don't map well to the idea of "happening first"; they're running *in parallel*.

Of course, you can change the odds by having a delay in the code for the parent, before the print-outs.

Not at all sure what you mean by "the control is transferred to the program"; since both processes will hit `exit()` very quickly after having printed their messages, there should be no program left to transfer control to.

Note that you don't need to use `exit()` from `main()`, it should end with a plain old `return` since its return type is `int`.

Comment: Control is transferred to program means as the programs completes its output the cursor still remains in the program !

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Okay ... I still find that very hard to believe, the program has no further content after you print and reach `exit()`, there's nothing to remain in. This must be some artefact of your environment, or something.

Comment: child goes to background? parent reaches `exit()` but child still executes. They are separate processes.

Answer (score 9):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
int main()
{
    int status;
    int pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid<0)
    {
        printf("\n Error ");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("\n Hello I am the child process ");
        printf("\n My pid is %d ",getpid());
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
       wait(&status);
        printf("\n Hello I am the parent process ");
        printf("\n My actual pid is %d \n ",getpid());
        exit(1);
    }

}
```

In this program the if (pid == 0) means child  and pid > 0 means parent so
  the parent and child are running in the same time access the same resource so the problem of the race condition occur.
  The which one is  first access the resource its executed first and another one is
  executed at later time.

The wait function avoid the race condition and  when the child execution complete
  until the parent wait and after executed the parent

The Default  vfork  avoid the race condition

```
        pid=vfork();

Because the vfork use the parent wait for until the child complete.
```

Also if you want to get the process ID of parent process. Use int ppid = getppid() function.

The output of the program is:

```
     Hello I am the child process 
     My pid is 7483 
     Hello I am the parent process 
     My actual pid is 7482
```